# asp.net - show phone number as link or not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a real simple ASP.NET MVC4 app that uses JQuery Mobile and displays a list of users and their information.  3 fields off the model are phone numbers.  These fields can contain a null value, so I'd like to link the phone number using `<a href="tel:"` if it exists, and nothing if not.  I came up with this:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="textinput1"><strong>Office Phone:</strong></label>
    if(!@String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.OfficePhone)){
        <a href="tel:@user.OfficePhone"><input name="" id="textinput1" value="@user.OfficePhone" type="text" readonly="true"/></a>
    } else {
        <input name="" id="textinput" value="@user.OfficePhone" type="text" readonly="true"/>
    }
</div>
```

But would think there's a cleaner, better way to do this.  Are there any other options or am I stuck with writing out the `<input>` tag twice in both conditions?

Comment: What would tel:// do?  As far as I know most smartphones automatically detect and enable telephone numbers as links.  It simply has to be in the text somewhere.  At least, that's how the iPhone does it.  In other words, I don't think you have to do anything to make it a clickable link in most environments for which making a phone call would be possible.  Update: RFC 3966 is what you're talking about.  Gotcha.

Comment: I should have stated that we are using JQuery Mobile as well(not too sure if that makes a difference with links or not).  I thought the same but after deploying my app in our staging environment, the phone numbers do not appear on my phone as links.  However, when I use tel: they show do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested code. Hopefully it gets the idea across:

```
@{string pref="tel:"}
@if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.OfficePhone))
{pref="";
}


<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="textinput1"><strong>Office Phone:</strong></label>
        <a href="@(pref):@(user.OfficePhone)"><input name="" id="textinput1" value="@(pref)@(user.OfficePhone)" type="text" readonly="true"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited a bit. My first pass was sloppy. But seems it got the point across. Good luck!